# Django-Piston - I Can't POST on a model with a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I'm trying to set up piston on my Django project. I ran into a brick wall when I tried to POST (create) a new entry on a model that contains a ForeignKey: **location**.

Here is the exact error I receive:

> Cannot assign "u'1'": "Fest.location" must be a "Location" instance.

In the above example, I tried to send over `location=1` in the POST.

What am I doing wrong here? Surely Foreign Keys are supported on CREATEs...

**Update:**
To be clear, I'm using PISTON to handle these REST API requests. My Handler currently looks like this:

```
class FestHandler(BaseHandler):
    model = Fest`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign an actual object.  Something like the following should work:

```
loc = Location.objects.get(pk=1)
obj.location = loc
obj.save()
```

where `obj` is the model you're trying to save which has location as a foreign key.

Comment: I don't think this will work in a PISTON handler, but I could be misunderstanding something...

Comment: This actually ended up working, I am just new to Django and didn't know exactly how to implement it.